# Jmeter - how to execute linux bash shell command/script through BeanShell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

please, advice how to how to execute linux bash shell command/script through BeanShell. The idea behind is to use this approach for setUp and teardown without taking place in final reports.

The goal is to setUp/tearDown test environment for each ThreadGroup

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend considering switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as:

1. Well-behaved groovy can be compiled into bytecode
2. Executing commands in Groovy is much easier, all you need is to add `.execute()` after the command and that's it

   - `"date".execute()`
   - `"date".execute().text`

Demo:

[image: Groovy shell execute demo]

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for more detailed information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

As Beanshell is Java (scripting lang), you can use below statement in Beanshell to run a specific command.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`

Comment: Hi vins, 

I tried with using BeanShell pre/post-processors in bellow structure

BeanShell pre-processor1(setUp test env - run shell script)
ThreadGroup1 
BeanShell pos-processor1(tearDown test env - run shell script)
....
BeanShell pre-processor2
ThreadGroup2
BeanShell pre-processor2
 
but in that case all pre-processors are been executed all before ThreadGroup1